# Proof that $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots=\ln2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

Proof that $\displaystyle 1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots=\ln2$.

I have read this answer but I don't understand the fifth line.
\begin{align*}
S_{2n}&=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}
\\&=\left(1+\frac13+\dots+\frac1{2n-1}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2n}\right)
\\&=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1{2n}\right)-2\left(\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2n}\right)
\\&=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1{2n}\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1n\right)
\\\color{gray}{[\text{ why? }]}\quad&=[\ln 2n+\gamma+o(1)]-[\ln n+\gamma+o(1)]
\\&=\ln2+o(1)
\end{align*}
when $n\to\infty$, with $\gamma=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1n-\ln n\right)$.

Otherway, $S_{2n+1}=S_n+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n+1} \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=\ln2$

Comment: This is a "well known fact" (for certain definitions of "well known"). The idea is that we can approximate $\sum_{i \leq n} \frac{1}{i}$ by $\ln(n)$. In fact, we can do it to relative error $\gamma$, the so called "Euler-Mascheroni Constant". You can read more on the wikipedia page for [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Comment: Thank you. This information's amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof uses the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right) - \ln n\right )$ converges to a particular value, $\gamma\approx0.577...$ By using the definition of a limit, we can write:

$$
\gamma = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right) - \ln n + \epsilon
$$

Where $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small by making $n$ larger and larger. (Values that behave this way can also be denoted by "$o(1)$")

Comment: Thank you. I understood.